# How to install eclipse plugin for HDP 2.2

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hortonworks-data-platform

I have Hortonwork Data Platform 2.2 (HDP) installed on a Windows Server 2012 and would like to install Eclipse plugin for it, I downloaded the plugin from [Github](https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin)  followed the instruction available at [this link](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/47/build-install-configure-eclipse-plugin-apache-hadoop) but I keep getting error. Has anyone had experience installing the HDP plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

remove your installation and step by  step  check this 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/47/build-install-configure-eclipse-plugin-apache-hadoop
if there was  any errors put it in comment and i ll try to help you as much as possible ..